# '!' symbol in <!DOCTYPE html>?

Tags: html

We generally use  for html5 declaration. But '!' refers to 'not' in computer science. So does it mean 'not DOCTYPE html'?

Comment: No, it's not a standalone `!`, it's a `<!DOCTYPE ...>`.

Comment: `!` refers to a lot of different things with computers and even with computer science in particular. For example, some proofs in computer science use factorials.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is documentation about [Document type declarations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_type_declaration) (DTDs) and [CDATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) in general.

CDATA structures add additional information about a SGML and XML document. They start with a `<!`, which is not a logical negation, just syntax. These structures aren't called tags, but *declarations*.

`<!doctype HTML>` just means that the following document is an HTML5 document. In the past, there have been several very complicated DTDs.